# Kotlin MutableLiveData clean or update

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

I am pulling data from api in my application. I keep the data I have in MutableLiveData. There is no problem so far. However, when I filter and pull other data, it lists the new data under the old data. My goal is to delete the old data and show only the new data.

> ViewModel

```
val breakingNews: MutableLiveData<Resource<NewsResponse>> = MutableLiveData()
    var breakingNewsPage = 1
    var breakingNewsResponse: NewsResponse? = null



     fun getCategoryNews(countryCode: String,category:String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    
    
Is it possible to do a check here?
            breakingNews.postValue(Resource.Loading())
            val response = newsRepository.getBreakingNews(countryCode,category,1)
            breakingNews.postValue(handleBreakingNewsResponse(response))
        }
  private fun handleBreakingNewsResponse(response: Response<NewsResponse>): Resource<NewsResponse> {
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            response.body()?.let { resultResponse ->
                breakingNewsPage++

                if (breakingNewsResponse == null) {
                    breakingNewsResponse = resultResponse
                } else {
                    val oldArticles = breakingNewsResponse?.articles
                    val newArticles = resultResponse.articles
                    oldArticles?.addAll(newArticles)

                }
                return Resource.Success(breakingNewsResponse ?: resultResponse)
            }
        }
        return Resource.Error(response.message())
    }
```

> Fragment(Observe)

```
 viewModel.breakingNews.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            when (response) {
                is Resource.Success -> {

                    hideProgressBar()




                    response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                        newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles.toList())
                        val totalPages =
                            newsResponse.totalResults / QUERY_PAGE_SIZE + 2 //Sayfada boşluk oluşuyor
                        isLastPage = viewModel.breakingNewsPage == totalPages
                        if (isLastPage) {
                            rvBreakingNews.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
                        }

                    }
                }
```

> Adapter.kt

```
class NewsAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ArticleViewHolder>() {
    var formatPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    inner class ArticleViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem.url == newItem.url
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ArticleViewHolder {
        return ArticleViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_article_preview,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size

    }


    private var onItemClickListener: ((Article) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ArticleViewHolder, position: Int) {

        val article = differ.currentList[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            Glide.with(this).load(article.urlToImage).into(ivArticleImage)
            tvSource.text = article.source?.name
            tvTitle.text = article.title
            tvDescription.text = article.description

            var formattedTime=setTime(differ.currentList.get(position).publishedAt)

            tvPublishedAt.text = formattedTime

            setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener?.let { it(article) }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is in either your repo's `getBreakingNews()` or in `handleBreakingNewsResponse()`, neither of which you showed. What's `newsAdapter.differ`? Usually you submit a list directly to the ListAdapter.

Comment: I didn't understand what you said first sir. How can I do something?

Comment: You could share the code of those functions so we can see if there's a mistake in them.

Comment: Sir, I edited the question. If there is something missing, tell me and I will add it.

Comment: are you caching the data into local as well in repository?